# Esconder parâmetros na URL com rotas e mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho uma rota assim:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "RotaConteudo",
    url: "Conteudo/{name}/{Parametro}/{tipo}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Conteudo", action = "Conteudo", name = "", Parametro = "", tipo = "" }
);
```

Quando sobe a página, minha url fica assim.

`..../Conteudo/argentina/3/3`

O `3/3` são os respectivos parâmetros passados na rota. Há como ocultá-los na URL?

Tenho um foreach(na home) que monta a minha URL, assim:

```
foreach (var item3 in item2.subconsulta2)
{
    if (item3.Id_SubCategoria2 != null)
        str = str + "<li><a href=\"/Conteudo/" + item3.Id_SubCategoria2 + "/3/" + retira_acentos(item3.SubCategoria2).ToLower().Replace(" ", "-") + "\" title=\"\">" + item3.SubCategoria2 + "</a></li>";
    else
        str = str + "<li><a>" + item3.SubCategoria2 + "</a></li>";
}
```

Ele envia esses parâmetros para um método que possuo em uma controller e ele vai no banco e pega o HTML correspondente a esse parâmetro. Se eu pudesse passar o parâmetro, que não fosse pela URL, eu refaria a Rota, para exibir apenas o nome, já que o HTML será mostrado pelo parâmetro passado de outra forma.

Comment: Tenho um foreach(na home) que monta a minha URL, assim: foreach (var item3 in item2.subconsulta2)
                       {
                           if (item3.Id_SubCategoria2 != null)
                               str = str + "<li><a href=\"/Conteudo/" + item3.Id_SubCategoria2 + "/3/" + retira_acentos(item3.SubCategoria2).ToLower().Replace(" ", "-") + "\" title=\"\">" + item3.SubCategoria2 + "</a></li>";
                           else
                               str = str + "<li><a>" + item3.SubCategoria2 + "</a></li>";
                       }

Comment: Edite sua pergunta e adicione esta informação que está em comentário, logo após de ter feito isto, delete o comentário.

Comment: @pnet: Cara, você não tinha 160 pontos? Agora tá só com 6???

Comment: Então, não sei o que aconteceu. Sempre postei direto, mas dessa última vez, me pediu para eu criar uma senha. Criei e pediu para criar um login. Fiz e deu nisso. Realmente o site ainda é meio confuso. Preciso fazer um tour e entender isso tudo.

Comment: @pnet: vi lá na lista de usuários... você acabou criando outro usuário com o mesmo nome. Pergunta lá no [meta.pt.stackoverflow.com](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/) como resolver esse problema.

Comment: @pnet Veja se ajuda ==> http://erraticdev.blogspot.com.br/2011/03/removing-route-values-from-linksurls-in.html

Comment: @pnet Você conseguiu sanar sua dúvida? Por favor, dê algum feedback sobre esta questão. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Para enviar dados para o servidor sem ser pela URL, o único jeito que eu conheço é via `POST`.

Agora o problema está em como fazer um POST partindo de um link... a forma que eu conheço é você criar um `form` na página e submeter o mesmo usando javascript no clique do link, e para ocultar alguns dos parâmetros, é só colocar `input`s dentro desse `form` e definir o valor dos mesmos antes de submeter via script.

**Exemplo funcional:** usando jquery

Rotas:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "RotaConteudo",
    url: "Home/{name}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Conteudo", name = "" }
);
```

Javascript:

```
function linkPost(e, params) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $form = $("<form action='' method='POST'></form>");

    for (var key in params)
        $("<input type='hidden'/>").attr("name", key).val(params[key]).appendTo($form);

    $form
        .attr('action', $(this).attr('href'))
        .submit();

    return false;
}
```

CsHtml:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Conteudo", new { name = "agt" })"
   id="open-popup"
   onclick="javascript:return linkPost.apply(this, [event, { parametro: 3, tipo: 3}]);"
>agt 3, 3</a>
```